# Windows 8.1 Auto start up

Tags: windows, settings, startup

I have a Windows 8.1 tablet that I need to be on 24/7. So if the power cuts out and the battery drains to 0% I need it to automatically start as soon as the power is back on and starting to charge the unit. How can I set this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "Task schedule" on windows could help you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Belal. Ive had somebody tell me that it can be done BUT they don't remember how... I'm really not liking my chances. :(

Comment: Awesome.. I will have a look and let you know :)

Comment: Unfortunately no luck.